# Getting wrong array values

Tags: c++, arrays

Printing the values of the arrays `digitArray` and `testo` shows incorrect values.

`Display.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>
#include "display.h"

#define D0 26
#define D1 27
#define D2 28
#define D3 29
#define BL 15
#define BM 16
#define BR 4
#define MI 5
#define TL 10
#define TM 11
#define TR 6
#define DOT 1

int segmentArray[8] = {BL, BM, BR, MI, TL, TM, TR, DOT};
int digitArray[4] = {D0, D1, D2, D3};
int testo[4] = {260, 1,2,3};

//Sets all segments on
void Display::test() {
    std::cout << digitArray[0] << std::endl;
    std::cout << D0 << std::endl;
    std::cout << testo[3] << std::endl;
    std::cout << segmentArray[0] << std::endl;
}
```

`Display.h`

```
class Display {
    public:
        void test();

    private:
        int SegmentArray[8];
        int digitArray[4];
        int testo[4];
};
```

`main.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "display.h"

int main() {
    Display display;
    display.test();

    return 0;
}
```

Running this code gives me:

```
35588 (incorrect, varies from time to time and appears to be some adress)
26 (correct)
0 (incorrect)
15 (correct)
```

Comment: There's no problem in the snippet you've posted. Please post [enough code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Code works fine - http://ideone.com/i3qDzI - problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Just added the full code.

Comment: `calcSegments` returns a pointer to a local variable. Your arrays do not persist after the function returns. Either return `std::array` or make the arrays static. Also, don't use macros for constants.

Comment: I'm going to change these things. But this part actually works.

Comment: There's now far too much code, in particular a dependence on a non-standard header which makes it impossible to compile. Please post [just enough code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I test your code and i obtain this values :

```
26
3 
26
15
```

When you write digitArray[0], you get the value of the index 0 in the array.
So 26 in your case.
For the second output you write testo[3] so you get the forth index of the array, so the value 3.
Remember that arrays begin at index 0 in C++...

Recompile your code, perhaps your latest modifications would not be saved...
Your first result seems to be an address.

Comment: I messed up the order of the outputs when is edited the post.
I recompiled it many times, but still get wrong values for these two arrays.

Comment: You have global variables in Display.cpp that have the same name as members of Display class. In your "cout", it is members that are used not global variables. Make a choice between member and global variables.

Answer (score 0):

`calcSegments` returns a pointer to a local array, which has been destroyed by the time you try to access it. Arrays are quite nasty things, which can't be returned (directly) by value, so I'd suggest returning

- `std::array<int, 8>` if the size is known to be 8 in all cases
- `std::vector<int>` if the size might vary.

Comment: I just removed the complete calcSegments method and recompiled everything. I'm still getting wrong values.

Comment: @Rarn34: You'd better get the debugger out then. Or reduce the code to a [minimal, self-contained test case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you want people to debug it for you.